# How recent are the tweets returned by Twitter's streaming API?

Tags: streaming, twitter

Does Twitter's streaming API (stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json) give the most recent tweets?  For example, current new york time is 9.20 AM, one of the tweets I got through this method had the created_date as Wed Oct 06 13:13:42 +0000 2010.  Does this mean the tweets returned by this API could be a few hours old?  Or does it return the latest tweets (as in few minutes or seconds old)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streaming API returns a sample of tweets - for non privileged users, it's only 5% of the stream.  You can request access to the Firehose, which is all tweets, but you must have a good reason to do so.  I think you can buy access too.

When dealing with user streams, [this doc](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/user_streams) indicates that you should be getting the data in near realtime, so I don't think you should see such a big delay.

**EDIT:** See [this](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/).  13:13:42 +0000 2010 is actually 9:13:42 EST.  I just checked, I'm on EST, 10:27 AM, and the time is 14:27 GMT +000.  Your results are very close to actual time within minutes, not hours.

Comment: It says near realtime, but looks like the tweets are a few hours old.

Answer (score 0):

Tweets from the streaming API are real-time. I run many tweet collection systems for clients, and everyone of them gets and displays tweets as soon as they are posted on Twitter. The delay between a tweet being posted and receiving it from the streaming API is usually a second or two.

Comment: But then on running the streaming API for a day , i am noticing that a lag is being developed eventually.